# How to display posts of a specific category onclick of menu options?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `Post` and `Category`.

**Post**

```
   pid   title    result    content      cid   
   1    Option1    Opt      content1      2   
   2    Option2    Opt      content2      2   
   3    Option3    Opt      content3      3
```

**Category**

```
   cid  cname   
   1     Cat 1    
   2     Cat 2    
   3     Cat 3
```

This is my **insert.php** .

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

mysql_select_db("database") or die("Unable to select database");

$title=$_POST['post_title'];
$result=$_POST['post_result'];
$content=$_POST['post_content'];
$sid=$_POST['cid'];
$date=$_POST['date'];

$insertquery="INSERT INTO review (post_title,post_result,post_content,cid,date)
          VALUES('$title','$result','$content',$sid,NOW())";


$result=mysql_query($insertquery);

if(! $result )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {

        echo "Entered data successfully\n";
        header('Location:home.php');
    }
```

This is my **cat.php** which displays posts of particular category.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("database");



$query="SELECT * FROM category WHERE cid='$cid'";

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query to get data failed with error:  ".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_num_rows($result)) { 
echo    //details goes here

}
```

This is my category menu list on home page .

```
<ul>            
<li><a class="my-button" href="#">Cat 1</a></li>
<li><a class="my-button" href="#">Cat 2</a></li>
<li><a class="my-button" href="#">Cat 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is javascript.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').on('click', '.my-button', function() {

   $("#display").load("cat.php");

   });
});
</script>
```

Everything is getting inserted to database correctly . But im not able to display the posts of specific category onclick.

I have given the complete code. What I want is, when I click on Cat 1 or Cat 2 or Cat 3 on home page I need to display all data from post table of the selected category in the `#display` div.

I am getting an error saying:

> cid is undefined variable

Please help me find the proper code.

Comment: "Do write the required code for me", are you kidding?

Comment: @doniyor: you shouldn't have... the OP belatedly asked ppl here to write his code for him... that's just revolting

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, i just wanted to keep the good weather around here.. :D

Comment: @doniyor: sure, but you're just hiding the grey clouds, wouldn't it be better if they were removed all together? (like: close a question because it doesn't fit the Q&A format of SO)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, :), yeah, you are right. but cannot close it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that is because looking at your script `$cid`, which is used in your query is not defined anywhere.  Kudos for at least ahving error reporting on.  Next time you really should read and understand the error messages you get, as this oftentimes tells you exactly what the problem is.

Also, you really need to look at learning mysqli or PDO. The `mysql_*` are depreacted and should no longer be used.  You also have sever SQL injection vulnerability, so you should read up on what to do about that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're taking wrong path. you are not sending any data to cat.php, hence $cid is undefined. Send category id to load.php to get back valid result. Something like

```
$("#display").load("cat.php",{cid: yourvalue});
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what is " yourvalue " . Is that to be taken from <li> or where ??

Comment: _yourvalue_ is the category id for which you want to load posts